# Openerp translation report

Tags: odoo

I am currently in the process of my company's computing using openerp.
I was wondering how I could translate the reports are exported to pdf files (ie the contents of the pdf document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally reports are automatically translated in the language of your user interface. So it would be enough to change the UI language (trough the settings menu in the upper right corner if your are with OpenERP 6.0).

If you want additionally your accounts names to be translated for example then you need to install the l10n_XX module for your country. But you need this module not only for account names so you may also have installed it.